# Do online recommendation systems ask specific questions about the PhD candidate?

Tags: phd, recommendation-letter, science

I am applying to fall 2014 PhD programs in computer science. I have heard that the online recommendation system in place at most universities asks the recommender to answer a series of questions about the student in addition to a place where the letter can be typed. What kind of questions are asked?

Comment: As a graduate applicant, why should you care? Your only decision is a judicious choice of folks who will write you strong research-y letters of recommendation.

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at this:
[image]

They pretty much ask the same sort of questions (mostly in a Likert scale).

Comment: FYI: the candidate name and program aren't quite blurred enough, I can almost make them out.  (Though maybe they are fake anyway.)

Comment: It is probably fake. I took it from Oregon State's website: http://gradschool.oregonstate.edu/help/docs/34#

Comment: I doubt if anyone's name is really "New Applicant".